# R - When to add a break

Tags: r

I have an exercise that compares efficiency of loop functions.

I have function

```
banana <- function(x)
{d <- length(x)
xi <- x[1:(d-1)]
xnext <- x[2:d]

sum <- sum(100*(xnext-xi^2)^2 + (xi-1)^2)
y <- sum
return(y)
}
```

I want to re-write the above using a for loop (or any loop). I have so far

```
for (i in x){
  n = length(x)
  y <- 100*(x[i+1]-x[i]^2)^2 +(x[i]-1)^2
  }
```

I want the function to stop at n-1 and having difficulty knowing where to add the break. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance,

Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really have to add a `break` statement, you can just loop over all but the `n`th i. 
`[-length(x)]` removes the last element from the sequence.

```
y <- 0
for (i in seq_along(x)[-length(x)]) {
  y <- y + 100 * (x[i + 1] - x[i])^2 + (x[i] - 1)^2
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That clarified things.